# Can I have a variable type as a input parameter for a stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters

For example, the parameter could be of `INT` type, or `FLOAT`, or `DATETIME`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add something the param as a varchar and then convert it to appropriate type using a CASE structure and then use it in your procedure,of sort:

---

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE v VARCHAR DEFAULT "NULL";

    CASE v
      WHEN 'INT' THEN CONVERT(v AS INT);
      WHEN 'FLOAT' THEN CONVERT(v AS FLOAT);
      ELSE
        BEGIN
        END;
    END CASE;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like `@Qty int` as your input parameter?

Comment: If the parameter would always be an int I would just type `CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN param INT)`. But in my case I want the parameter type to be dynamic so `param` could be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

every time you have to manually edit the store function to change the data type.